# Migrate web project run in tomcat 6 java 1.6 to tomcat 8 java 1.8

Tags: java, tomcat8, tomcat6

Currently want to migrate the web project that run in tomcat 6 java 1.6 to tomcat 8 java 1.8. When the tomcat 8 is startup in eclipse and pull the project that using java 1.6 from git, i can access to the web page. However, when i want to stop the tomcat i cannot terminate(have to end the task in task manager). After that i startup the tomcat again it wouldn't startup also. Note that this web project doesn't have servlet and have ant xml file. There have some scheduler run using quartz.

Comment: When startup eclipse console log doesn't show any error

Comment: Need some more data ... The problem statement is confusing ...

Comment: Start with making a hello world web app work in your setup first.